# EDITED -- locally stored variables not quite working

Tags: jquery

This is my second jquery project ever and I am trying to make a kind of simple choose your own adventure game. The class it is for has covered beginning html, css, and jquery. I am trying to create a system where I can add items to an array based on clicks and then display the contents of that array as the user's "inventory". The array also needs to be stored locally. What I have so far:

**NEW STUFF HERE**

**Thanks for the replies I get a few days ago. I tried working with these answers and also talked to a tutor a bit and changed some of my approach. However things are not really working and I can't figure out why. Here is my new code so far:*

```
$(document).ready(function() {

//$(document).keydown(function(event) { 

//alert("Hello"); });

//^ alert is a test to see if the files are hooked up right    






  if (localStorage.getItem("lightp") === null) {
      localStorage.setItem("lightp", 0);
      }

   localStorage.getItem("lightp")

    $( ".light" ).click(function() {
   lightp++;
   localStorage.setItem("lightp",lightp);
});
    var light= localStorage.getItem("lightp");  

 if (light > 0) { alert("Hello") };

//^this is intended to create a locally stored variable that i can use to keep track of clicks as the user navigates the game. The alert is supposed to try to test if the number is actually increasing but either it doesn't work or I wrote something wrong or both.




$(".rope").click(function (event) { localStorage.setItem("hasRope",true)});

if (localStorage.getItem("hasRope") ===true){("#inventory").append("<p>Rope</p>")}; 

//^ since there are very few items in my game, my tutor suggested instead of trying to work an array I just use an individual local variable for each item. This is supposed to create the localStorage item when you click on the "rope" class link. The the script is supposed to check if the "rope" localStorage is defined and if it is, append the "rope" <p> into a div with the id "inventory", but that doesn't seem to work either.

});
```

Thank you for taking a look. I am not really experienced enough to be good at bug hunting yet.

Comment: look at localStorage for storing the values locally...

Answer (score 0):

You have to access the string by index

```
for (var i = 0; i < inv.length; i++) {
   $("#inventory").append("<p> contents of inv[0] = "+ inv[i] + "</p>");
}
localStorage.setItem("inv", inv); // store it locally
```

You can also use

```
$('#inventory').append("<p> contents of inv = " + inv.join(",") + "</p>");`
```

by joining the array by your separator of choice. And you could get back your stored array by doing

```
var arr = localStorage.getItem("inv");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

```
//read the already stored value
var strInv = localStorage.getItem('inventory');
var inv = strInv ? JSON.parse(strInv) : [];

$(".rope").click(function (event) {
    //some text to the stored/shown
    var string = $('#input').val();
    //if no value is entered, don't do anything
    if (!string) {
        return;
    }

    inv.push(string);
    //add the new value to inventory
    $("#inventory").append("<p>" + string + " </p>");

    //store the updated array
    localStorage.setItem('inventory', JSON.stringify(inv));
});

//Set the initial values
for (var i = 0; i < inv.length; i++) {
    $("#inventory").append("<p>" + inv[i] + "</p>");
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/xmy1yegs/)